# How to get the Logitech MX518's DPI adjustment buttons to work with USB Overdrive?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, osx-snow-leopard, logitech-mouse

I have a Macbook Pro running Snow Leopard, but recently I've been needing to use an external keyboard. When I'm making music, I've got a lot of hardware sitting between me and the screen (USB numpad, audio interface, 71 key korg keyboard, and possibly manuscript paper). I'm also using a second monitor and DejaMenu.

I'm using an old HP keyboard and a Logitech MX518 mouse. I'd like to be able to assign one of the DPI buttons on the MX518 to the key command that opens DejaMenu so if I'm fiddling around on the other screen I don't have to move the mouse to the other screen or touch the keyboard.

I've been using the trial version of SteerMouse, and it works perfectly with the mouse. However, I'd also like to be able to configure my keyboard as well. So USB Overdrive would have been great for that, except it can't override the DPI-adjustment functions of buttons 7 and 8 (+ and - ) on the mouse. Losing a couple of buttons isn't that bad, but it also always starts up on the lowest DPI setting, which is unnecessarily irritating.

I've also tried ControllerMate, but I wasn't able to program a macro that was reliable for activating the Application Switcher via a single button press.

Anybody have any luck with getting the MX518 to work with USB Overdrive, or can perhaps recommend another reasonably priced gaming mouse with 8 buttons and similar precision as the MX518 that they've successfully used with USB Overdrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was afraid to try this initially, but it seems that if you have both USB Overdrive and SteerMouse installed it won't break.

Just disable the "Any Mouse" setting in USB Overdrive so SteerMouse can take control.

I had SteerMouse installed first, then added USB Overdrive. USB Overdrive then superseded SteerMouse except for mouse handling, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you search well, you can find software that let you use your logitech mx518 under macosx. (In fact, all logitech mouses).
Try this link:

http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/drivers/logitechcontrolcenter.html

Comment: Unfortunately the Logictech Control Center doesn't work with the mx518. Or, if there's some aspect of it that does (couldn't get it to respond to anything I needed it to), it's not useful at all, and did weird things to my global mouse settings.